# How to create a shortcut to a website installed in IIS using an MSI Installer created using a Visual Studio 2010 Setup project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web, setup-project, web-deployment-project

I have created a Setup project for Visual Studio 2010 installing a website directly under IIS, but after installing it in IIS, I want to create a shortcut for the application in my desktop, so that after I click the shortcut icon it should open the application directly from the desktop which is created in IIS. How can I achieve this from my Visual Studio Setup project?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach:

1. Create an *IE favorite* for the newly installed site, resulting in an URL-shortcut.
2. It is (so far has always been) a text file with `.URL` extension of the following format:

   ```
   [InternetShortcut]
   URL={0}
   IDList=
   HotKey=0
   IconFile={1}
   IconIndex=0
   [{000214A0-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}]
   Prop3=19,2
   ```
3. Add a Custom Action to the Setup project, capturing necessary details (like site URL) and spitting them out into an URL-shortcut, placed on e.g. Public Desktop (thus available to every user).
4. The icon (set by `IconFile={1}`) is the hardest part:  the only thing that works reliably and sticks, is a local path (like `C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\MyApp\AppIcon.ico`), obviously that works only on that local machine.  Any attempt to use an URL to an icon (similar to how *favicons* work) does not seem to work or survive a reboot (the icon is lost).  But i can live with that.

Note:  Shortcut extension **must** be capitalized (`.URL`) to function properly on Windows 7!

Once you figured out step 3, add an Uninstall Custom Action to remove that URL-shortcut. :)